# Android less resource-heavy WebView?

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I'm working on a news reader app at the moment, and unfortunately their API makes heavy use of HTML blocks.

Right now I'm using a dynamically loaded fragment and into that I load a stack of WebViews to display this HTML content. It is simple, no JS, basic CSS (fonts and text styles, no dingy-wingy background styling and whatnot), and basic HTML4 features.

However this stack of WebViews makes loading significantly slower. This simple app can eat up to 120MB RAM on an xhdpi device with only one article open.

I've thought about using a TextView with `Html.fromHtml(content)`, but then styling goes off, and it also inserts the CSS style as text.

Is there a less resource-hungry solution for displaying small HTML content (preferably something that can work in a stacked view, e.g. LinearLayout, and wraps the content). As I said, no major features like JS needed.

It is important to have separate web views as the content has various types, which require separate formatting (e.g. images are sent as simple URLs, and are converted server-side to proper size), and the HTML views, while in majority, are not the only ones.

Comment: you can use one webview and lots of iframes -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: I could, but as I said, there are other elements sent from the server, elements which I draw manually (because of specific design, which renders faster if done natively).